# Racetrack or standard kegs?

Tags: kegging, keg, corny-keg

I purchased a pair of ball lock corny kegs at a garage sale recently, and they are in great shape, although they're missing the top cap.

Is there an easy way to tell whether they are standard or racetrack? Are there standard measurements available for each size, so I could measure the opening and discover it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racetrack keg lids are straight on the long sides, whereas standard keg lids are curved all the way around. Images help.

[This is a standard keg lid.](http://www.kegoutlet.com/keg-lid-reconditioned-all-standard-kegs.html)

[This is a racetrack keg lid.](http://www.kegoutlet.com/keg-lid-reconditioned-racetrack-style.html)

If there are any straight lines on your keg lid opening then it's probably a racetrack.